# Unlink Phone from a Specific User

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

The following Google Cloud Function should **unlink the phone number from a specific user.** If the code was executed on the client, it would look like the following. However, (currentUser) is undefined, which makes sense because the cloud function does not know anything about the current user.

What should I replace (currentUser - below) with?

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

module.exports = async function (request, response) {   
/* eslint-disable */
    admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(request.body.phoneNo)
        .then( (userRecord) => {            
            // WHAT SHOULD I REPLACE currentUser (BELOW) WITH? 
            admin.auth().currentUser.unlink(firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)
                .then ( () => {
                    console.log("getUserByPhoneNumber - unlink - then"); 
                })
                .catch( (error) => {
                    console.log("getUserByPhoneNumber - unlink - catch - error:", error); 
                })
            ;
            response.send({ success: true });
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.log('getUserByPhoneNumber - catch - error:', error); 
            response.send({ success: false });
        });
/* eslint-enable */
};
```

I tried the following with no success. 
`admin.auth().getUser(userRecord.uid).unlink(firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)`
`admin.auth().userRecord.unlink(firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)`

Thank you for your effort and time to help...

Comment: `unlink()` is not something supported in `firebase-admin`. There's no way to implement this in a Cloud Function as far as I know. Here's the full API surface of `admin.auth()`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove the phone number from a user via Admin SDK, here is how you do it:

```
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    return admin.auth().updateUser(userRecord.uid, {phoneNumber: null});
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // Phone number should be cleared from the user record.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error occurred.
  });
```